# Read application.properties before creating Spring application context

Tags: java, spring-boot

As a part of a Spring Boot project, I am trying to read the application.properties before I create the Spring ApplicationContext as follows,

Main class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurationClass con = new ConfigurationClass();
        con.readProperties();
        ApplicationContext c = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration class,

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ConfigurationClass {

    private String value1;

    private String value2;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public void readProperties() {
        value1 = env.getProperty("app.value1");
        value2 = env.getProperty("app.value2");
    }

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }
}
```

I want do get some basic values from the application.properties and do some configurations. What happens with this code is that it throws a `nullpointerexception` since `env` is null during `value1 = env.getProperty("app.value1");`.

What am I doing wrong here?

How do I read the values in application.properties at this point of time before creation of the springapplication context?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you please elaborate on "do some configurations" because to me this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Are the properties truly application properties or environment properties? I might be wrong here and I am sure experts would correct me , but i believe the applicationContext must exist before the properties can be loaded. Basically the configObject is a spring managed bean, and for spring to "manage" it , the applicationContext must exist. If they are truly environment variables, you can inject them at runtime

Comment: Reading the properties and making them available is part of the bootstrapping proces of Spring Boot. So no this isn't possible as `@ConfigurationProperties` are part of Spring Boot. Why do you need this? You should use the `ConfigurationClass` in your configuration where needed (the properties are read very early in the process). Feels like you are working around spring boot or aren't understanding parts of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class ConfigurationClass {
        @Value("${app.value1}")    
        private String value1;

        @Value("${app.value2}")    
        private String value2;

        public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
        }

        public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
       }
 }
```

Then Call it

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext c = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    ConfigurationClass  con = c.getBean(ConfigurationClass.class);
    System.out.println(con.getValue1());
    System.out.println(con.getValue2());
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm my case I'm trying to set SSL debugging  (e.g., `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake:verbose");`  **before** initializing the SpringContext, because the SSLContext is created during Spring's dependency injection.  If I set it afterwards, it's too late.  My guess is I need to fall back to Java code to read the `src/main/resources/application.yml` file.  The work around is to change the startup script to include this property on the java command line `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose`.